# Proportional min width in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I find it very difficult to understand, WPF allows me to set proportional width but not minWidth ! I mean:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="126*"/>                 // OK
<ColumnDefinition Width="126*" MinWidth="126*"/> // NOT ALLOWED
```

How would you set min/max width/height proportionally ?

Comment: My best guess is it's because that would mean the minimum width for the object isn't actually a minimum width anymore, since it could now be any size. If you want that behavior, I would probably just use a converter to translate a * size to an actual numeric size.

Comment: Because it makes no sense.   Width="126*" MinWidth="125*".  Width will always be bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it makes no sense

Width="126*" MinWidth="126*"
same as
Width="126*"

Width="126*" MinWidth="125*"
same as
Width="126*"

Width="126*" MinWidth="127*"
same as 
Width="127*"

Comment: I disagree, I want the initial size be 10% and min size be 10% too, it could be bigger but not smaller.

Comment: What?  126* = 126*   every time    And proportion is not just initial - it is a portion of the current size.

Comment: you're right. I should change proportionality to address my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add an attached property. This could monitor the grid for changes and keep the min width adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Here is an example in general which will give you the overall concept:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/692265/WPF-Custom-Attached-Property